# Jquery-UI disabling input fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui

Using Foundation Framework and PHP

I have a couple of simple input type=text form fields which appear to get focus (cursor blinks inside them) but they refuse to accept any keyboard input. After some trial and error, I discovered that if I disable the Jquery-ui.js script, the inputs work ok.

It appears that Jquery-ui is somehow disabling the fields. Does anyone have any idea why this might be and what a workaround might be? I need to keep Jquery-ui as I have some draggable/droppable items.

```
<form action="#" method="post">`
  <input id="formLength" type="text" >`
  <input id="formWidth" type="text">`
</form>`
```

Comment: Code of your form please.

Comment: In case anyone is interested, I resolved the problem by moving the script for Jquery-ui from the Head to the foot of the page and the problem went away!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here, but i've seen errors like these when i had conflicting jquery mask plugins in the project. I needed to use both, so i had to deactivate the duplicated selectors from one of the libs so it doesn't activated for the same input.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough information to answer the direct question. However, as a side note, you can use the  jQuery UI interactions--mouse, position, draggable, droppable, position, resizable, selectable, sortable--without having to use the widgets. The only dependencies are core.js and widget.js(the widget factory).

Answer (score 0):

I've got a potential workaround for you.

## First create two instances of jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $jOriginal = jQuery.noConflict(); 
</script>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var $jNew = jQuery.noConflict(); 
</script>
```

## Now, use new jQuery instance in place of the old one

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $jNew('#selector).doSomething(); //Will use new jquery library
    $jOriginal('#selector).doSomethingElse(); //Will use original jquery library
</script>
```

Comment: Trying to understand how this would help, perhaps I'm missing something. The inputs are just HTML, I'm not using any Jquery at that point